# My model is magenta in Texturing Paint. What does it mean?

Tags: texturing

I try to add texture to my cat. 
My model is Magneta color in Texturing Paint. What doesn't it meaan?
[image]

When I select ViewPort Texture is like this.
[image]

I try to put hair in my cat. I don't know how .
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That magenta means that the material of your cat has a non assigned texture; the colored checkboard means that an UV map has been created referring to that image.

Open a UV Image editor window, select the colored checkboard, save it to your hard drive with a name like "Cat skin";
Select your material and load the saved "cat skin" as an image texture.
Now you should be able to paint it in texture paint mode.
It should work both in Cycles and Blender Internal.

To make your cat furry you will have to add to the skin material a new "hair" particle system and play with the adjustements.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In texture paint mode, you need to add a paint slot of your choice from the Tools menu. Probably, you would choose Diffuse from the drop down. Above that, you can choose between Image if you want to adjust a texture or Material to paint it by hand from scratch.